# cakephp slow because of mod_rewrite?

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a web made with CakePHP 1.3.10. This web seems to get slower every time new folders/pages are added to it (which happens pretty often).

I believe reading somewhere that the mod_rewrite found in the 3 .htaccess files may have something to do with it.

Is it true?

I'm trying to get it to work without the htaccess files, but all my links are messed up. Is there any way to avoid having to edit all the links in the website? Now it seems that I have to add **/app/webroot/** before every file I'm linking (css, js, etc) and add **/index.php** before every link in the website.

Is this the only way?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's because mod_rewrite or not, but reducing the amount of files and folders of the website improves de load times significantly

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured how much time is spent in mod_rewrite and how much in PHP? In my experience the most likely problem is the time Cake spends looking for files in the file system, which gets progressively worse when you add files and directories.

You can use Xdebug to profile the application, or just add calls to print the time in appropriate places in the framework to see how much time has passed since the beginning of the request.

Comment: I've been running tests using this website (http://fpt.pingdom.com/) to measure the loading times. It seems that the more folders/files I add to the file system, the "wait time" for the page I'm testing grows. Do you think this could be because of mod_rewrite? If deleting it will make the website run faster, I don't mind doing all the work, I just don't want to do it for nothing (there's a lot of stuff to change)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a mod_rewrite issue. The time it takes to transform an URL like `http://example.com/wiki/Page_title` to something like `http://example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Page_title` is more or less constant, and doesn't grow with the number of files/directories as they are irrelevant for the rewriting process.